# cordova-plugin-googlemaps where is API_KEY saved?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, api-key

I am using [this](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) plugin for cordova. I want to know where IOS and Android API KEY is saved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the keys in the following files:

**iOS:**

platforms/ios/{your appname}/{your appname}-Info.plist

**Android:**

platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml